How to deal with numerical inaccuracy in a parallel sum scan required for sampling?
I am doing a parallel sum scan on a vector x of probabilities. All the elements of the float32 vector x are between [0,1] and sum up to 1. I have a Cuda kernel using such a vector to sample indices from a probability distribution, and the first step in that discrete sampling function is to do an inclusive sum scan in order to get a cumulative probability vector y.
But I realized that in that vector y, it doesn't hold that for every y[i-1] <= y[i] and this is causing indices which have a probability of 0 to be sampled.
I think this is due to numerical inaccuracy and I am not sure what to do about it. Maybe add 1 to move the x vector's values into the [1,2] range, and then take the mantissa of that as an int, before doing all of the later steps in unsigned integer arithmetic.
Is there anything better I could do?

The numerical stability of an algorithm is dependent of the precise/exact algorithm used. Tiny details can have a huge impact (e.g. y-x1+x2 != y+(x1-x2)), for example because of things like FP non-associativity, and such details are not provided.

Do you use thrust's inclusive scan or did you write it yourself? I find it somewhat hard to believe that this condition occurs unless there is a bug or an issue with the data but I could be overlooking something

I wrote it myself. That link is for a working version. I managed to work around the issues by filtering out the 0 elements from the sum scan based on the original vector as well as getting the leftmost element in the sampling kernel after subtracting the target probability (instead of the minimal element.) I apologize, I know that code probably looks like gibberish and my explanation doesn't make sense. It is amazing how many issues I ran into with the discrete sampling kernel.

I wrote some test code to simulate the issue and could reproduce it with thust::inclusive_scan. Any increase in numeric accuracy, like switching to double or using Kahan summation, would only reduce the chance of this occurring but not remove it.
Instead I think it is okay to just filter this problem away with a running maximum filter. We know that mathematically, the values should never decrease. So any occurrence of that is just numerical noise. Filtering that should not invite any risks but I'd be happy to hear some comments on that.
In any case, an extra
thrust::inclusive_scan(vector, vector + vecsize, vector, thrust::maximum<float>{}) after the first prefix sum should do the trick. Here is the full test code. The fix is between the #if 1 … #endif preprocessor directives for easy removal. Compile with nvcc -lcurand -lnpps testcode.cu
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <curand.h>
#include <npp.h>

#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/scan.h>

#include <algorithm>
// using std::max
#include <cstdio>
// using std::printf


int main()
{
    const int vecsize = 1024 * 1024;
    const int iterations = 10000;
    float* rndvec, *normalized, *inscan, *diffs, *hostvars;
    for(float** vec: {&rndvec, &normalized, &inscan, &diffs})
        if(cudaMalloc(vec, vecsize * sizeof(float)))
            return 1;
    /*
     * nppsSum_32f and nppsMinMax_32f store their results in device memory.
     * We use pinned host memory accessible by both to retrieve it without memcpy.
     * But we need a cudaDeviceSynchronize() before accessing the values
     */
    if(cudaHostAlloc(&hostvars, 3 * sizeof(float), 0))
        return 2;
    float* sum = hostvars, *min = hostvars + 1, *max = hostvars + 2;
    curandGenerator_t gen;
    if(curandCreateGenerator(&gen, CURAND_RNG_PSEUDO_DEFAULT))
        return 3;
    if(curandSetPseudoRandomGeneratorSeed(gen, 0xbad1dea))
        return 4;
    int sumbufsize, minmaxbufsize;
    if(nppsSumGetBufferSize_32f(vecsize, &sumbufsize))
        return 5;
    if(nppsMinMaxGetBufferSize_32f(vecsize - 1, &minmaxbufsize))
        return 6;
    Npp8u* nppbuf;
    if(cudaMalloc(&nppbuf, std::max({sumbufsize, minmaxbufsize})))
        return 7;
    for(int i = 0; i < iterations; ++i) {
        /* Generate random values range (0..1] */
        if(curandGenerateUniform(gen, rndvec, vecsize))
            return 8;
        /* We want range [0..1) so as a clutch, we subtract the minimum */
        if(nppsMinMax_32f(rndvec, vecsize, min, max, nppbuf))
            return 9;
        if(cudaDeviceSynchronize())
            return 10;
        if(nppsSubC_32f(rndvec, *min, rndvec, vecsize))
            return 11;
        /* Normalize so that their sum is 1.0 */
        if(nppsSum_32f(rndvec, vecsize, sum, nppbuf))
            return 12;
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        if(nppsNormalize_32f(rndvec, normalized, vecsize,
                  0.f /*subtracted*/, *sum /*divided*/))
            return 13;
        /* verify normalization */
        if(nppsSum_32f(normalized, vecsize, sum, nppbuf))
            return 14;
        /* perform inscan, a.k.a. partial_sum */
        thrust::device_ptr<float> normalized_ptr(normalized);
        thrust::device_ptr<float> inscan_ptr(inscan);
        thrust::inclusive_scan(normalized_ptr, normalized_ptr + vecsize,
              inscan_ptr);
#     if 1
        /*
         * Optional fix: Filter numerical noise.
         * We know the value should never decrease,
         * so we just force that
         */
        thrust::inclusive_scan(inscan_ptr, inscan_ptr + vecsize,
              inscan_ptr, thrust::maximum<float>{});
#     endif
        /* compute pairwise differences of adjacent values */
        if(nppsSub_32f(inscan, inscan + 1, diffs, vecsize - 1))
            return 15;
        if(nppsMinMax_32f(diffs, vecsize - 1, min, max, nppbuf))
            return 16;
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        std::printf("mindiff %g maxdiff %g sum %g\n", *min, *max, *sum);
        if(*min < 0.f) /* abort if the result ever gets negative */
            return 17;
    }
    std::puts("No error detected");
}


I didn't think about using a max scan. It's not a bad idea, but it wouldn't have worked for the sampling kernel unless I also masked out the 0 probabilities from the original array. I had issues with it selecting the masked-out elements that were out of bounds before I did that.
